# Twig variables to javascript array.push

Tags: javascript, twig, opencart-3

I want to pass twig variables to javascript .push

My code in twig file:

```js
var order_id = '{{ order_id }}',
  total = '{{ total }}';
console.log(order_id);
console.log(total);
(window.b24order = window.b24order || []).push({ id: order_id, sum: total });
console.log(window.b24order)
```

I see the values in console but in array.push is nothing

Comment: if what you say is true, your code should work fine! see here: https://jsfiddle.net/ahbmpk3c/

Comment: `(window.b24order=window.b24order||[]).push({id: order_id, sum: total}); console.log(window.b24order);` does not show the correct array?

Comment: window.b24order is your new array. .push() will only return the length.

Comment: As you can see in the snippet I made you, if your twig vars contain anything they will be pushed

Comment: Your code works. Please delete the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You overwrite your `window.b24order` array with the return value of `push()`, which returns the new length, not the modified array. The array is already modified.

[JavaScript Array.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

**Change to this approach:**

```js
    var order_id = '{{ order_id }}',
      total = '{{ total }}';
    console.log(order_id);
    console.log(total);
    window.b24order = window.b24order || [];
    window.b24order.push({ id: order_id, sum: total });
    console.log(window.b24order)
```

Comment: This is not correct. The statement does not overwrite anything as I showed in the snippet. `(window.b24order = window.b24order || []).push({ id: order_id, sum: total });` assigns the existing b24order OR an new array and then pushes to it. OP's code works

Answer (score 0):

**The push() method adds new items to the end of an array, and returns the new length.**

You are assigning new length of b24order array after pushing to b24order.

Comment: And this means what? OPs code works and can be closed as a not-reproducible question

Comment: as above question is edited with the correction, question can be closed now